# Flask app is running correct function, but not rendering template

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app with a template. I am attempting to send via post several items collected by javascript when the user clicks a button. When I post my data to /confirm, the print statement executes, but the render_template function does not render anything, my web browser stays on the /likes page.

Here is the web_interface.py:

```
#!/bin/python3

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import twitter as twitter
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


form_data = {}
tweet_data = {}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/likes", methods=['POST','GET'])
def likes():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tweet_url = request.form['inputTweetURL1']
        liking_user_list = twitter.liking_users_lookup_by_url(tweet_url)
        return render_template("likes.html", liking_user_list=liking_user_list)
    else:
        return render_template("likes.html")


@app.route('/confirm', methods=['POST'])
def confirm():
    #block_list = json.loads(request.data.decode())["data"]
    # print("Print the data: {}".format(foo))
    block_list = json.loads(request.data.decode())['data']
    print(block_list)
    return render_template("confirm.html", block_list=block_list)

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

And here is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method='POST'>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="inputTweetURL1" class="form-label">Tweet URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputTweetURL1" id="inputTweetURL1"
            aria-describedby="inputTweetURL1Help">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="scrollme">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <!-- Table headers -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">User ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Profile URL</th>
                <th scope="col">Follower Count</th>
                <th scope="col">Verified Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Block User</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Table body -->
        <tbody class="table-group-divider">
            <!-- For loop logic of jinja template -->
            {%for user_data in liking_user_list%}
            <!-- Table rows -->
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>{{user_data['name']}}</td>
                <td>{{user_data['id']}}</td>
                <td><a href="https://twitter.com/{{ user_data.username }}">https://twitter.com/{{ user_data['username']
                        }}</a></td>
                <td>{{user_data['public_metrics']['followers_count']}}</td>
                <td>{{user_data['verified']}}</td>

                <td><a><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary toggle-button">Block</button></a></td>

                {%endfor%}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="danger-report" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add click event listener to a button with an ID of "danger-report"
        $('#danger-report').click(function () {
            // Get all the buttons with the btn-danger class
            var dangerButtons = $('.btn-danger');

            // Filter out the rows that contain the danger buttons
            var dangerRows = dangerButtons.parents('tr');

            // Define an empty list to store the contents of the <td> elements
            var tdContents = [];

            // Log the number of danger rows and their contents to the console
            dangerRows.each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(); // Get the text content of the first <td> element in the row
                var id = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(); // Change '1' to the index of the <td> you want to log
                var url = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text(); // Change '1' to the index of the <td> you want to log
                var followers = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text(); // Change '1' to the index of the <td> you want to log
                var verified = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text(); // Change '1' to the index of the <td> you want to log


                var item = { "name": name, "id": id, "url": url, "followers": followers, "verified": verified }

                tdContents.push(JSON.stringify(item));
            });

            //console.log(tdContents)
            // Join the contents of the tdContents array with commas
            var dataToSend = tdContents.join(',');


            var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
            r.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/confirm", true);
            r.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
                //alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
                console.log("Sent");
            };
            // Send data in below way from JS
            r.send(JSON.stringify({ "data": dataToSend }));
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I can't figure out why when posting r.send the template isn't rendered. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Here is the updated routing:

```
@app.route('/confirm', methods=['POST','GET'])
def confirm():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #block_list = json.loads(request.data.decode())["data"]
        # print("Print the data: {}".format(foo))
        block_list = json.loads(request.data.decode())['data']
        #print(block_list)
        print('youre posting, it worked')
        return render_template("confirm.html", block_list=block_list)
    else: 
        block_list = json.loads(request.data.decode())['data']
        print('youre gettin')
        return render_template('confirm.html', block_list=block_list)
```

And here is the function where the POST request is sent. Is this where I need to do the redirecting?

```
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/confirm", true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
        //alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
        console.log("Sent");
        //window.location.href = "/confirm"; // Redirect to /confirm
    };
    // Send data in below way from JS
    r.send(JSON.stringify({ "data": dataToSend }));
    
    window.location.href = "/confirm";
```

Comment: check from browser's developers tools if the response contains data. i suspect its your JS code that doesnt redirect you to `/confirm` or prints data on page.

Comment: Why do you expect that your template will be rendered? You're not doing anything with the response from the server.

Comment: The response contains data. If you look at the python file, I print(block_list), and it always has the correct data. The next line is return render_template, and that isn't doing anything.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Shouldn't the web_interface.py see that it is receiving data from the POST method, then follow the directions? It prints block_list correctly, but doesn't render the template.

Comment: My guess is that it *does* render the template and sends the HTML as a response. But your client doesn't have any instructions what to do with the response.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I checked, you are right, the HTML is received as a response. I see it in my browsers dev tools network tab under the name "confirm", and when I click on it it shows the HTML that is supposed to be rendered. How can I render it? I am very confused.

Comment: When I click preview under my network tab, after clicking on confirm in the list of items, it shows the full and correct html. It does not, however, render it in the browser.

Comment: I would recommend that you redirect with JavaScript to a different URL which renders the page for you. Use a similar setup like how you did your `/likes` endpoint with a GET method, but for your `/confirm` endpoint. Whenever you send a POST request to `/confirm`, just respond with a message that lets you know it worked. Then on the client, after a successful response, redirect to the `/confirm` endpoint. This will send a GET request to your server. That's where you should respond with your HTML.

Comment: When you say 'then, on the client, after a successful response, redirect to the /confirm endpoint' how on earth would I do that? I updated my routing, which I think is correct, and I am adding it to the original question. I just don't understand how to redirect or where? Is it in my javascript after the request has been sent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252146/discussion-between-emiel-zuurbier-and-mowsie2k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the logic by sending the ids of the selected rows to the `/confirm` endpoint. Then let the endpoint figure our what data the ids represent and render it for you.

```
@app.route('/confirm', methods=['GET'])
def confirm():
  args = request.args
  ids = args.get('ids')
  id_list = ids.split(',')
  return render_template('confirm.html', id_list=id_list)
```